# how can i make concurrent requests with postman?

Tags: testing, post, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I need to test my web API with postman, my web API is post web service and it will called by another services.
if anyone has guideline for this case I would be thankful for helping.
thank you

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157105/how-to-make-multiple-requests-at-the-same-I time-using-postman

Answer (score 1):

You could use Runner (button top left in latest Postman).

Every time you click it, it opens another Collection Runner so you could run iterations concurrently but perhaps not with as much control as you might need over which calls are run at the same time?

Comment: thank you Ben
Postman has not enough tools for my scenario and I forced to run my test by Jmeter, but thank you for your attention.