# Execute a request a given number of times (postman)

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

Related to:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157105/postman-how-to-make-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time#:~:text=Just%20create%20a%20runner%20with,to%20bring%20up%20multiple%20instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157105/postman-how-to-make-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time#:%7E:text=Just%20create%20a%20runner%20with,to%20bring%20up%20multiple%20instances).

but I need to make the same request a given number of times. E.g. for an endpoint:

```
(GET) http://localhost/gadgets/{{gadget_id}}/buy_gadget
```

the gadget_id variable can be read from a file but this leads to multiple GET requests with a different id. How can I make a predefined number of requests to the same endpoint with the same gadget_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow get the `gadget_id` and the number of runs, since that is not part of the core question here, I'm simply setting those as environment variables.

In the pre-request script, if an environment variable `counter` is not existing, it is being set to `1`. If it is existing, it is being increased by `1`:

```
pm.environment.set("gadged_id", 1234);
pm.environment.set("numberOfRuns", 3)

if (!pm.environment.get("counter")) {
    pm.environment.set("counter", 1);
} else {
    let counter = parseInt(pm.environment.get("counter"));
    counter++;
    pm.environment.set("counter", counter);
}
```

In the test tab, it is being checked if the number of runs has already been reached. If not, the same request is being called again via `postman.setNextRequest()` (you need to adabt the parameter value of `postman.setNextRequest()` to the name of your request). If it has been executed often enough, the `counter` variable is unset:

```
let numberOfRuns = parseInt(pm.environment.get("numberOfRuns"));
let counter = parseInt(pm.environment.get("counter"));

if (counter < numberOfRuns) {
    postman.setNextRequest("buyGadget");
} else {
    pm.environment.unset("counter")
}
```

Comment: Does postman.setNextRequest("buyGadget"); call the same url with the same gadget_id (in this case)?

Comment: Yes, it is being called with the very same pre-request script, which in this example will always be the same, since it is hardcoded. You could also make that dependend on `numberOfRuns` and/ or `counter`.