# How to send multiple GET requests in postman?

Tags: python, json, postman

My intent is to check the behaviour of GET call when we send multiple requests in a single call.
Say for example.

1. GET https://{IP}:8181/restconf/
2. GET https://{IP}:8181/restconf/data

I want to send both the requests at one time so that i should get body params for both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: How to make multiple requests at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157105/postman-how-to-make-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

**newman command line utility is not designed for sending multiple request in parallel**,

**but you can use powershell** to try running collections multiple times.

```
$TargetPath=".\newman"
if (test-path ".\newman") {Remove-Item -r $TargetPath -Force}
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -path ".\newman\reports"
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -path ".\newman\logs"

For  ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    $TestNewmanArgs="a.json -r cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export newman\report-$i.html"
    $argz="run $TestNewmanArgs -k 
    "$i"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Roaming\npm\newman" -ArgumentList $argz -PassThru
}
```

just store this as ps file and then right click and use run with powershell

this will execute newman in multiple cmd processes

**You can also use newmna as a nodejs library and write code to run the scripts in parallel**

Answer (score -1):

Postman doesn't have any feature for parallel requests. [Postman collection runner](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/) might help but the requests occur sequentially.

> The Collection Runner allows you to run sets of requests in a specified sequence. The Collection Runner will log your request test results, and your scripts can pass data between requests as well as altering the request workflow.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183449/12431598).

Comment: Collection runner executes the requests in sequence, not in parallel.