# Postman or Newman: Run several collections in parallel sharing common variables

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

This is my first question on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anyone asking or answering this question.

I have four collections in Postman that I want to run in parallel. I want all of the collections to be running at the same time, but I want to have a shared environment of global variables that each of the collections will be updating in real time and pulling from as well.

I know how to run several collections in parallel with Newman as answered here: [Postman: How to make multiple requests at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157105/postman-how-to-make-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time)

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7304360/volodymyr-popelniuk does the trick there for me.

I've seen this issue that shows that there are issues with setting and getting global variables with newman: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/831

This is what I want to do:

1. Run all 4 collections in parallel
2. Use postman.globals.set("var", var) for setting variables and postman.globals.get("var") for getting variables
3. Have a call in collection 1 set a variable and a call in collection 2 call that same variable later

I'm having trouble with the globals not being set or called in a common scope for the four collections. Here's the code I have calling it:

```
var path = require('path'),
  async = require('async'), 
  newman = require('newman'),

  collection1 = {
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Device 1.postman_collection.json'), // your collection
    environment: path.join(__dirname, 'Tenant - QACLOUD-TWO.postman_environment.json'), //your env
    reporters: ["cli"]
  };
  collection2 = {
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Device 2.postman_collection.json'), // your collection
    environment: path.join(__dirname, 'Tenant - QACLOUD-TWO.postman_environment.json'), //your env
    reporters: ["cli"]
  };
    collection3 = {
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Device 3.postman_collection.json'), // your collection
    environment: path.join(__dirname, 'Tenant - QACLOUD-TWO.postman_environment.json'), //your env
    reporters: ["cli"]  
};
  collection4 = {
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'Device 4.postman_collection.json'), // your collection
    environment: path.join(__dirname, 'Tenant - QACLOUD-TWO.postman_environment.json'), //your env
    reporters: ["cli"]
};
parallelCollectionRun = function(done) {
  newman.run(collection1, done);
};

parallelCollectionRun1 = function(done) {
    newman.run(collection2, done);
};

parallelCollectionRun2 = function(done) {
    newman.run(collection3, done);
};

parallelCollectionRun3 = function(done) {
    newman.run(collection4, done);
  };

// Runs the Postman sample collection thrice, in parallel.
async.parallel([
    parallelCollectionRun,
    parallelCollectionRun1,
    parallelCollectionRun2,
    parallelCollectionRun3
  ],
  function(err, results) {
    err && console.error(err);

    results.forEach(function(result) {
      var failures = result.run.failures;
      console.info(failures.length ? JSON.stringify(failures.failures, null, 2) :
        `${result.collection.name} ran successfully.`);
    });
  });
```

The result is that all the collections are run successfully in parallel, but none reuse the global vars.

I'm even open to scrapping all of this and moving to Node or JS to accomplish what I need, but I'm hoping there's something in Newman that I just haven't thought of yet.